# Is there a way to combine multiple list comprehensions in Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Here's a function in my code:

```
def get_weights(Last_scan, Peak_shot):
    Est_Succshots = [x*Peak_shot for x in Last_scan.values()]
    Est_error = [np.sqrt(i)/Peak_shot for i in Est_Succshots]
    Is = [1/m for m in Est_error]
    Weights = [i/sum(Is) for i in Is]
    return Weights
```

I used 4 list comprehensions to do the calculation. I wonder is there a shorter way or a different approach I can perform such calculations? Thanks for the help:)

Comment: I would say this is a good case for just using a for loop instead of list comprehensions. There is no reason to be creating a new list at every step when you could just use a for loop and do all the calculations at once while being equally readable.

Comment: You can combine all your mapping ops into a single one. Not sure if that's better.

Comment: not sure you need a second loop here, id go with `Is = [1/(np.sqrt(i)/Peak_shot) for i in Est_Succshots]` and drop Est_error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `Last_scan.values()` is a list of numbers and `Peak_shot` is a number, this seems to be equivalent to

```
def get_weights(Last_scan, Peak_shot):
    Is =  np.sqrt(Peak_shot/np.array(Last_scan.values()))
    return Is/Is.sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Yes `Last_scan` is a dictionary and `Peak_shot` is a number. It returns `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'dict_values'`

Comment: In such case replace `Last_scan.values()`  by `list(Last_scan.values())`.